# How to connect Ubuntu system to mac OS computers on ethernet LAN?

Tags: 14.04, networking, mac

I have a local network in the house that has Apple computers with Mac OS on it, except the Ubuntu 14.04.3 system I now have on one computer (an Intel Macmini).  The mac's connect using either IP addresses I assigned back when I set it up or afp (Apple file protocol) addresses. I'm a longtime extensive user of personal computers, almost entirely Mac's, but I'm not a "techie" and don't do code at any level.  I like the Ubuntu system but I can't find how to connect the Ubuntu computer with the Mac's for file exchange, etc. ...Do not want to do it via internet.

Comment: Please clarify what "Do not want to do it via internet" means for you. Are you suggesting serial line, or IR, or bluetooth?

Comment: He meant LAN connection

Comment: I mean I want to keep it within the house, not go via a connection to an ISP.  The computers are now all connected physically by ethernet cables through a hub and a switch and I would prefer to continue this way but bluetooth would be OK, if nececessary.